# Intelij: "Files commited" but not showing in Github?

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, gradlew

I have built my Project using `"gradlew build idea"`

I linked my project to GitHub and performed my `initial commit` using the instructions on the Website.

However when I commit changes from my `change lists` it says `"files commited"` yet when I check my GitHub repository they are *not* there?

What do I need to do to configure to `Intelij` with my exact Repository on `GitHub`?

Comment: Did you push to Github servers?

Comment: Yes I was able to from the command line with initial commit, but I cannot seem to within Intelij?

Comment: You need to push your changes.  This is a step which is different from  committing.

Comment: how do I do this in Intelij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I commit changes from my change lists it says "files commited" yet when I check my GitHub repository they are not there?

In order to see your files on the remote repository you have to push them.
Once you commit the file are only inside your local repository.

Here is the basic flow that you will need to follow:

[image]

Comment: I did not know this, so essentially when commiting them inside Intelij I am just commiting them to my local? Then I need to push them from outside Intelij?

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](http://www.github.com) is a git storage website, which you use as a remote.  `git` repos can be completely local if needed.  If you have never pushed before, run:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git push origin master
```

Don't commit using `intellij`.  Use the command line.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

Comment: I have done this, the issue I am having is commiting my file through intelij which doesnt work. I can commit/push files using the cmd line or tortoise git, but not from intelij?

Answer (score 0):

All the changes you commit are saved in Local. So, you need to push the changes from Local to Remote. For this, right click on master in Local and you can see Push option.
[Please refer the attached screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JoS3.png)